# Unexpected Jump in `movementX` and `movementY` Values in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent, microsoft-edge, web-development-server

I'm experiencing an unusual issue with mouse event handling in Chrome and Edge browsers (latest versions), which I don't encounter in Firefox. The problem involves unexpected jumps in the values of `movementX` and `movementY` during mouse movement.

**Background**:
I am developing a web application that requires precise mouse movement tracking. I use `requestPointerLock()` to lock the mouse pointer for an immersive experience. The application heavily relies on the `movementX` and `movementY` properties of `MouseEvent` to track the mouse's movement.

**Issue**:
When I move the mouse slowly, the values of `movementX` and `movementY` occasionally jump to a large number (e.g., from around 1 to 627), indicating a sudden, unrealistic change in the mouse position. This issue seems to occur only in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox.

**Code Sample**:

```js
// Sample code demonstrating how I handle mouse events
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    let movementX = event.movementX;
    let movementY = event.movementY;

    // Process the movement
    // ...
});
```

**Attempts to Resolve**:

- I have tried implementing a moving average filter to smooth out the values, but the issue persists.
- Considering the possibility of a browser-specific issue, I have tested this on the latest versions of Chrome and Edge, as well as on Firefox where the issue does not occur.

**Question**:
Has anyone else encountered this kind of behavior in Chrome and Edge? Are there any known issues with how these browsers handle `movementX` and `movementY` in `MouseEvent`, especially when the pointer is locked? Any insights or suggestions on how to handle these unexpected jumps in mouse movement values would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**?

Answer (score 1):

This had been an issue in Chromium-based browsers for a long time, and has to do with mice with high polling rates, but they finally provided a work-around in Chromium 88+. See the bottom of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69672260/8916663